# How to capture a particular line from terminal output?

Tags: command-line, networking, scripts

So i used `ip route` command it shows output like this

```
 default via 192.168.43.162 dev wlp8s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp8s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlp8s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.230 metric 600
```

How can I use it in an automated sh script so that it runs this command in terminal ?

```
adb connect addressgateway:5555
```

For example Where address gateway is 192.168.43.162 captured from `ip route`

Comment: Seems an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Are you asking how to get the default gateway? You can just add this alias to your `.bashrc`: `alias adb-connect-to-gw="adb connect $(ip route | awk '/default/ {print $3; exit}'):5555"`

Answer (score 0):

1. To get the output of your first command to another command you can use pipe |.
2. To cut specific line on output you can use `cut` command.
3. On this specific example you can use the following command:

   - `ip route | head -1 | cut -c12-24`
   - the output will be the ip.
4. To use it on a script you can use:

   - `#!/bin/bash`
   - `ip route | head -1 | cut -c12-24 > output.txt`
   - `variable=$(cat output.txt)`.
   - `adb connect $variable:5555`
5. To use the commands more specific and on other cases you can look for:

   - `man cut`
6. **Remarks:**

   - pipe `|` taking the first command output and use it on the next command.
   - `cut` command helps to filter the output you need.
   - `man` its like a guide page on the command.
   - `variable` its a temporary variable name to use, you can use any name you want to.
   - `$variable` is executing the alias that has been saved under the "nickname" name.

hope that will help you out.

Comment: There is no need to use a file to assign the variable. You can just run `adb connect $(ip route | awk '/default/ {print $3}'):5555`

Comment: Also, we can tell `ip` to give the `default` route directly: `ip -o route show default`